# Pandas - Extracting value to basic python float

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract a cell from a pandas dataframe to a simple floating point number. I'm trying

```
prediction = pd.to_numeric(baseline.ix[(baseline['Weekday']==5) & (baseline['Hour'] == 8)]['SmsOut'])
```

However, this returns

```
128   -0.001405
Name: SmsOut, dtype: float64
```

I want it to just return a simle Python float: `-0.001405`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Output is `Series` with one value, so then is more possible solutions:

- convert to `numpy array` by [`to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) and select first value by indexing
- select by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html)

```
prediction = pd.to_numeric(baseline.loc[(baseline['Weekday'] ==5 ) & 
                                        (baseline['Hour'] == 8), 'SmsOut'])

print (prediction.to_numpy()[0])

print (prediction.iloc[0])
print (prediction.iat[0])
```

Sample:

```
baseline = pd.DataFrame({'Weekday':[5,3], 
                         'Hour':[8,4], 
                         'SmsOut':[-0.001405,6]}, index=[128,130])
print (baseline)
     Hour    SmsOut  Weekday
128     8 -0.001405        5
130     4  6.000000        3

prediction = pd.to_numeric(baseline.loc[(baseline['Weekday'] ==5 ) & 
                                        (baseline['Hour'] == 8), 'SmsOut'])

print (prediction)
128   -0.001405
Name: SmsOut, dtype: float64

print (prediction.to_numpy()[0])
-0.001405
print (prediction.iloc[0])
-0.001405
print (prediction.iat[0])
-0.001405
```

Comment: `item` is deprecated now

Comment: Wait, I just switched to get_values and it's deprecated too! `FutureWarning: The 'get_values' method is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use '.to_numpy()' or '.array' instead.`